# Updating TreeList ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm trying to update a Devexpress `TreeList`'s `ItemSource`. It appears to work the first time I press my button, but then it doesn't work anymore... Is there something else I have to update to change the `ItemSource`.

**Code**

```
window.randButton.Click += delegate
            {
                string st = window.nList.CurrentCellValue.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Called: "+st);

                try {
                    window.treeList.ItemsSource = null;
                    window.treeList.ItemsSource = drawOrderBook(currCycle, st);
                    // currCylce is static data
                    // drawOrderBook computes what to display based on the filer st
                }
                catch(Exception er) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(er.ToString());  }


            };
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with `DevExpress` Grid.

As per their guidelines/technical support you've to call [`RefreshDataSource`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_RefreshDataSourcetopic) method when data soruce is modified/changed.

So your code should be something like this.

```
window.randButton.Click += delegate
{
    string st = window.nList.CurrentCellValue.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Called: "+st);

    try 
    {
        window.treeList.ItemsSource = null;
        window.treeList.ItemsSource = drawOrderBook(currCycle, st);
        window.treeList.RefreshDataSource();
        // currCylce is static data
        // drawOrderBook computes what to display based on the filer st
    }
    catch(Exception er) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(er.ToString());  }

};
```